# HTML/Bootstrap Is there anyway to display a large string with numbers as an ordered list? Working within Django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I'm building a gym workout database website with Django, and one aspect of my Workout model is instructions. Since I accepted the instructions as a text field:

```
instructions = models.TextField()
```

Therefore it displays all as a jumble, ie.

`1. Adjust the bench to an incline of 15–30 degrees. 2. Lie back on the bench with the dumbbells, and, once in position, engage your core. 3. Press the dumbbells toward the ceiling. Your palms should be facing forward. Rotate your shoulders outward to engage your lats. Your upper back should remain tight and stable throughout the entire set.`

I'm wondering if there's a way to use regex, or some bootstrap class to reformat this into an ordered list where it is separated by individual steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by splitting `instructions` using the following regex: `"[0-9]+\. +?"`, which matches a number with 1 or more digits followed by a dot character and one or more spaces, *e.g.*, `"1. "`, `"234.   "`, etc. Then, format the resulting lines using bootstrap's `list-group` and `list-group-item` to generate a list group along with the associated list items' numbers.

The following function receives the instructions and regex as arguments and returns a string with the instructions' individual steps formatted as an ordered list for bootstrap.

```
import re

def format_instructions(instructions, regex = "[0-9]+\. +?"):
    split_by_number = re.compile(regex).split(instructions) # splits instructions into steps

    no_empty_str = filter(None, split_by_number) # removes resulting empty strings

    steps = list(map(str.strip, no_empty_str)) # removes spaces at the beginning and at the end of each step

    html = """<ul class="list-group">""" # list group begins

    for i, step in enumerate(steps):
        html += '\n    <li class="list-group-item">{}. {}</li>'.format(i + 1, step) # concatenates list group item

    html += "\n</ul>" # list group ends
    
    return html # returns formate instructions
```

Example:

```
instructions = "1. Adjust the bench to an incline of 15–30 degrees. 2. Lie back on the bench with the dumbbells, and, once in position, engage your core. 3. Press the dumbbells toward the ceiling. Your palms should be facing forward. Rotate your shoulders outward to engage your lats. Your upper back should remain tight and stable throughout the entire set."

formatted = format_instructions(instructions)

print(formatted)
```

Output:

[image]

This assumes there are no matching strings are within the instruction steps. Otherwise, the regex must be modified accordingly.